# Calculating route with pgrouting

Tags: routes, postgis, pgrouting

How can i, if it's even posible, calculate a route between two points using only existing points as a source? No network/roads provided, i have only points.
I've tried this http://docs.pgrouting.org/dev/src/tsp/doc/index.html, but i think i'm getting wrong way.

Comment: TSP is for the shortest route that visits all points. What kind of route are you trying to calculate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't with pgRouting. You can only calculate the straight line distance between the points. To compute a route that would follow a road network you have to have the road network. You might try to use something like Google Maps API or Project-OSRM API. Both of these are web services that have the road network on a remote server and you can pass them the points and they will calcuate the route.

Comment: My problem is that i need to draw routes inside a building. Do you know any solution or where should i look for?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Then you will have to construct the edges for the hallways, stairs, elevators, etc. then you can do it using those. Think about the problem like. I ask you how to get from the living room to the laundry room in my house. Without a plan you can't do it. Well the computer needs a plan also. you supply the plan as a list of all possible edges that are in the building and then pgRouting can figure out the best way to make the route from those edges.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think i'll try to mess around with IndoorOSM http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/IndoorOSM then process data with pgRouting.

Comment: @ArmanKhubezhov if you have Java knowledge it should be easily possible to import any kind of data into GraphHopper, not just OSM.